# How can I deep link into QuickBooks Online with results from API calls that don't include the txnId

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

QuickBooks Online (QBO) uses a URL format like `qbo.intuit.com/app/timeactivity?txnId=123` to point to, in this example, a `TimeActivity`.

However, in the API, resources are referenced by `entityId` (returned as just `Id` when querying via the TimeActivity API), which is different from `txnId`.

In my time tracking web app, I have a feature that exports time to QBO as TimeActivities. I'd like to provide users with direct links from the time entered in my app to the corresponding TimeActivity in QBO—is there any way to do so?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify whether you are using the v2 or v3 QBO API.

Comment: @minimul This question is not about the API, it's about linking to QBO.

Comment: Post your question over at https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com – Intuit engineers hangout over there. Not so much on SO. You can also submit a support ticket from https://developer.intuit.com/v2/ui#/support – It will get answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is that it's not currently possible because there's multiple base URLs (I think they call them "realms") in use for QuickBooks Online (`qbo.intuit.com` is only one of them). Because you do not receive this information as part of linking to QBO via OAuth, there's unfortunately no way to construct proper links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when creating a successful TimeActivity you will receive back an `Id`, which I assume you are persisting.
That `Id` can be used to query QBO in a simple GET request.

```
<baseURL>/company/{companyID}/timeactivity/{timeactivityId}
```

Comment: I don't want to query the API, I want to deep link users to the API, so this answer is not applicable.